# como actualizar un data table limpiando los registros al hacer click en un boton?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

Tengo el siguiente código el cual este adentro de un p:fieldset, son dos inputs uno para el año y otro para el mes, y un boton de buscar, lo que hace es filtrar registros de acuerdo a esos dos parametros

```html
<p:inputText id="anio" style="width:100px;" value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.annio}"></p:inputText>

 <p:inputText  style="width:100px;" value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.mes}"></p:inputText>
 
 <p:commandButton   value="Buscar" icon="ui-icon-search"  styleClass="element-button green"  style="margin-right: 15em;"  id="buscar" 
                                           action="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.buscaDetalleIncidencia()}" update="consultaIncidencia,detalle" process="@form"  >
                        </p:commandButton>
```

el cual manda a llamar el siguiente  método

```html
public void buscaDetalleIncidencia() {
        System.out.println("ENTRO AL METODO BUSCA DETALLE POR AÑO/MESSS");

        incidenciaAnioMes = incidenciaAnioMesService.consultarIncidenciasAnioMes(new IncidenciaAnioMes(annio, mes, new Persona(cvePersona)));

        incidenciaAnioMesDet = anioMesDetService.findIncidenciaAnioMesDeByAnioMes(cvePersona, annio, mes);

        fechasIncidencias = crearFechaIncidencia(incidenciaAnioMesDet, annio, mes);

    }
```

Lo que hace es que al hacer click en el botón, muestra una tabla con todos los dias del mes que se ingreso en el input del mes, por ejemplo si se puso el numero 3, entonces muestra todos los días del mes de marzo, si se ingreso el 2, muestra todos los días del mes de febrero y así

Lleno la tabla con la lista "fechasIncidencias" la cual esta adentro del metodo,

```html
<p:dataTable id="detalle" var="detalle" value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.fechasIncidencias}" emptyMessage="No se encontraron registros." selectionMode="single" selection="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.fechaIncidencia}" rowKey="#{detalle.fecha}">

  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.seleccionaFecha}" update=":form:carDetail" oncomplete="PF('modalIntentos').show();" />
  <p:column headerText="FECHA" style="width: 100px;">
    <h:outputText value="#{detalle.fecha}">
      <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
    </h:outputText>
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="ENTRADA" style="width: 100px;">
    <h:outputText value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.horaEntradaBiometrico}">
      <f:convertDateTime type="date" timeZone="CST" pattern="HH:mm:ss" />
    </h:outputText>

  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="SALIDA" style="width: 100px;">
    <h:outputText value="#{detalle.incidencia.horaSalida}">
      <f:convertDateTime type="date" timeZone="CST" pattern="HH:mm:ss" />
    </h:outputText>
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="INCIDENCIA">
    <h:outputText value="#{detalle.incidencia.incidencias.cveIdIncidencia} - #{detalle.incidencia.incidencias.concepto}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="ACCIÓN" style="width: 100px;">
    <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-search"></h:outputText>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

a esa lista le paso un metodo, el cual se compone de la siguiente manera

```
public List<Date> crearFechas(int annio, int mes) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.clear();
    calendar.set(annio, mes - 1, 1);

    List<Date> fechas = new ArrayList<>();
    while (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == mes - 1) {
        fechas.add(calendar.getTime());
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }
    return fechas;
}

public List<FechaIncidencia> crearFechaIncidencia(List<IncidenciaAnioMesDet> incidenciaAnioMesDet, int annio, int mes) {
    List<Date> fechas = crearFechas(annio, mes);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    for (Date fecha : fechas) {
        FechaIncidencia fechaIncidencia = new FechaIncidencia();
        fechaIncidencia.setFecha(fecha);
        calendar.setTime(fecha);
        for (IncidenciaAnioMesDet incidencia : incidenciaAnioMesDet) {
            if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == incidencia.getDia()) {
                fechaIncidencia.setIncidencia(incidencia);

                break;
            }
        }
        fechasIncidencias.add(fechaIncidencia);
    }
    return fechasIncidencias;
}
```

lo que hago es crear una lista de fechas tipo Date a partir del mes y del año que se ingresen en los input

entonces al yo ingresar el año 2018 y el mes 3 y le doy en el boton buscar, me pinta la tabla con todos los dias de mes
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando cambio de mes, por ejemplo el 2 y le doy en buscar de nuevo, si me pinta todos los dias de febrero, pero los pinta seguidos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces, quiero que al hacer una nueva búsqueda la tabla se actualice, o sea que borre los datos del mes anterior y pinte solamente los nuevos
como le puedo hacer para actualizar la tabla?

Answer (score 2):

Debes limpiar o inicializar la lista (**fechasIncidencias**), te sigue manteniendo el resultado anterior por que no estas limpiando la lista, agrega la siguiente linea:

```
fechasIncidencias = new ArrayList<>();
```

La puedes poner en el metodo **buscaDetalleIncidencia()**:

```
public void buscaDetalleIncidencia() {
        System.out.println("ENTRO AL METODO BUSCA DETALLE POR AÑO/MESSS");
        fechasIncidencias = new ArrayList<>(); //Aqui

        incidenciaAnioMes = incidenciaAnioMesService.consultarIncidenciasAnioMes(new IncidenciaAnioMes(annio, mes, new Persona(cvePersona)));

        incidenciaAnioMesDet = anioMesDetService.findIncidenciaAnioMesDeByAnioMes(cvePersona, annio, mes);

        fechasIncidencias = crearFechaIncidencia(incidenciaAnioMesDet, annio, mes);

}
```

o dentro del método **crearFechaIncidencia()**:

```
public List<FechaIncidencia> crearFechaIncidencia(List<IncidenciaAnioMesDet> incidenciaAnioMesDet, int annio, int mes) {
    List<Date> fechas = crearFechas(annio, mes);
    fechasIncidencias = new ArrayList<>(); //Aqui

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    for (Date fecha : fechas) {
        FechaIncidencia fechaIncidencia = new FechaIncidencia();
        fechaIncidencia.setFecha(fecha);
        calendar.setTime(fecha);
        for (IncidenciaAnioMesDet incidencia : incidenciaAnioMesDet) {
            if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == incidencia.getDia()) {
                fechaIncidencia.setIncidencia(incidencia);

                break;
            }
        }
        fechasIncidencias.add(fechaIncidencia);
    }
    return fechasIncidencias;
}
```

Comment: excelente, gracias!